# Writing a batch script to start services

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I'm writing a script that will start Windows services that are supplied within a defined list:

```
set SERVICE_LIST=( "service1" "service2" )

for %%A in %SERVICE_LIST% do (
    net start %%A
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo "...Service [%%A] started successfully" & goto :nextservice
    if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 echo "...There was an issue starting service [%%A]"
    :nextservice
)
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
) was unexpected at this time.
```

Am I unable to define all of the error catching for each service within the `do()` block? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
set "SERVICE_LIST=service1,service2,..."

FOR %%A in (%SERVICE_LIST%) DO ...
```

Comment: I don't believe the declared list is an issue, as I have managed to print the contents of it using set SERVICE_LIST=( "service1" "service2" )

for %%A in %SERVICE_LIST% do echo %%A

Comment: oh, i c.  Because there is no effective command after the label ":nextservice" except ")", so you got that error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the `:nextservice` line: you should not include *labels* nor `goto` commands inside a `( block )`. BTW it is a bad practice to modify the syntax of commands storing parts of them in a variable...

```
set SERVICE_LIST="service1" "service2"

for %%A in (%SERVICE_LIST%) do (
    net start %%A
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
       echo "...There was an issue starting service [%%A]"
    ) else (
       echo "...Service [%%A] started successfully"
    )
)
```

Comment: `if errorlevel 1` won't work as desired if the return value is negative, e.g., due to an exception in `net.exe`.